# Fact check: Where in the Likutei Moharan does Rabbi Nachman talk about the Noam Elimelech?

Tags: sources-mekorot, breslov, noam-elimelech

When reading [this article](https://www.geni.com/people/%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%A7-%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99-%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9A-%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%96%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%A1%D7%A7/5216775740160079001) about the [Noam Elimelech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elimelech_of_Lizhensk) my curiosity was piqued after reading this line:

> Rabbi Nachman of Breslov says in his book, “Likutei Moharan,” that:
>
> *“The level of holiness of the holy Rabbi Elimelech is transcendent high above anything seen or understood within his book.”*

**My question**: Is this written in the Likutei Moharan? If so where?

Comment: How is this relevant to Judaism rather than just Jews?

Comment: @DonielF How is it _not_ relevant to Judaism? TrustMeI'mARabbi asked a _very_ relevant question: Does Rebbe Nachman mention Sefer Noam Elimelech in Likutei Moharan, as the article claims?

Comment: @ezra That sounds like a question about people, not a question about the religion they practice.

Comment: @DonielF It's a question about Jewish texts, not about people, which is very much on-topic.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/132745/sell-a-sefer-torah-to-buy-likutay-moharan/132916#132916

Answer (score 7):

**ספר חיי מוהר”ן סימן תקנג**.

> …כשראה (רבי נחמן מברסלב) את הספר הקדוש “נועם אלימלך” התפלא מאד ואמר:
>
> שקדושת מעלת הרב הקדוש רבי אלימלך ז”ל נשגבה למעלה למעלה ממה שנראה ומובן
>   מתוך ספריו הקדושים הנ”ל.

***Sefer Chayey Moharan*** Ch. 553

> When he (Rabbi Nachman of Breslov) saw the holy Book "*Noam
>    Elimelech*", he was greatly enthused, and he said that
>    “The level of holiness of the holy Rabbi Elimelech is transcendent
>    high above anything seen or understood from within his book."

Comment: Are you saying it's **not** in likutei moharan or you just found this alternative quotation.

Comment: Please Elaborate. But not bad answer +1

Comment: @TrustMeI'mARabbi I believe it is not in the Lekutei Moharan, because when the Chaey Moharan cites something which is stated in the Lekutei Mohran, the source in LM is cited along with it. Here it is not.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in the below images, a search for the word "Elimelech" (אלימלך) in Likutei Moharan did not produce any results.

[image]

[image]

For an alternative source for this claim, see [the other answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/93338/13438).