# Sell a Sefer Torah to buy Likutay Moharan?

Tags: chasidut-hasidism, breslov

I have heard on several occasions that Nachman of Breslov states that Likutay Moharan is such an important work that one must even sell a Torah scroll in order to purchase it.

Does anyone have the precise citation where he says this?

(To be clear: asking for the source, **not** opinions on the shita)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I haven't found him go to the extent saying sell a sefer torah, but in [Chayei Moharan 349](https://www.sefaria.org/Chayei_Moharan.349.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) his talmid [Rav Nosson Sternhartz of Nemirov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nathan_of_Breslov) relates:

> פַּעַם אַחַת הָיָה מְשַׁבֵּחַ אֶת הַסֵּפֶר שֶׁלּוֹ מְאֹד, וְאָמַר שֶׁיְּכוֹלִין לִהְיוֹת נַעֲשֶׂה בַּעַל תְּשׁוּבָה גָּמוּר עַל־יְדֵי לִמּוּד הַסֵּפֶר שֶׁלּוֹ. וְהָיָה חָפֵץ וּמִשְׁתּוֹקֵק מְאֹד שֶׁיַּדְפִּיסוּ סִפְרוֹ עוֹד כַּמָּה פְּעָמִים וְיִתְפַּשְּׁטוּ בָּעוֹלָם. וְאָמַר שֶׁיִּהְיוּ בְּנֵי אָדָם שֶׁיִּלְמְדוּ וְיִתְפַּלְּלוּ עַל־יְדֵי הַסֵּפֶר הַזֶּה. וְאָמַר שֶׁמִּי שֶׁיֵּשֵׁב וְיַעֲסֹק בִּסְפָרָיו רַק בְּלִי קִנְטוּר וְנִצָּחוֹן, וְיִסְתַּכֵּל בּוֹ בֶּאֱמֶת אָז בְּוַדַּאי יִהְיוּ נִבְקָעִין אֶצְלוֹ כָּל גִּידֵי קַשְׁיוּת לְבָבוֹ. וְאָמַר בְּזוֹ הַלָּשׁוֹן: "סֶע וֶועט אִים אַלֶע אָדֶערְן טְרֶענֶען". **וְאָמַר שֶׁכָּל אָדָם צָרִיךְ לְהִשְׁתַּדֵּל לִקְנוֹת הַסֵּפֶר שֶׁלּוֹ. וּמִי שֶׁאֵין לוֹ בַּמֶּה לִקְנוֹת יִמְכֹּר וְכוּ' שֶׁיֵּשׁ לוֹ וְיִקְנֶה זֶה הַסֵּפֶר שֶׁלּוֹ. וּמִי שֶׁאֵין לוֹ וְכוּ' יִמְכֹּר כַּר מִתַּחַת ראֹשׁוֹ וְיִקְנֶה הַסֵּפֶר שֶׁלּוֹ.** וְעוֹד סִפֵּר מִזֶּה וְעַיֵּן בְּמָקוֹם אַחֵר עוֹד מִזֶּה. וְאָמַר שֶׁהַסֵּפֶר שֶׁלּוֹ יִהְיֶה חָשׁוּב מְאֹד, וִיבַקְשׁוּהוּ וִיחַפְּשׂוּהוּ מְאֹד וְיֻדְפַּס וְיַחֲזֹר וְיֻדְפַּס כַּמָּה וְכַמָּה פְּעָמִים וְיִהְיֶה חָשׁוּב מְאֹד, רַק נִכְסַפְתִּי לִרְאוֹת זֹאת וְאֶהְיֶה אֲנִי עוֹמֵד וּמִסְתַּכֵּל מִן הַצַּד אֵיךְ לוֹמְדִים בּוֹ וּמַדְפִּיסִים אוֹתוֹ. וְאָמַר שֶׁהַמַּאֲמָרִים שֶׁכָּתַב בְּעַצְמוֹ גַּם הַלָּשׁוֹן לְבַד הוּא מְסֻגָּל מְאֹד כִּי הֵם כְּלָלִים
>
> Once there was someone who praised his book very much, saying that one is able to become a baal teshvah through studying his book. He wished and hoped very much that it would be printed many more times and spread around the world. He said that people would learn from it and pray through it. He said that whoever sits and studies his books without control and victory, and truly contemplates it, will surely have his heart's difficulties resolved. And he said in this language: "Go and take all the knowledge". **And he said that everyone needs to strive to buy his book. And whoever doesn't have the means to buy it should sell what is under his head and buy this book.** And one should keep reading and looking in other places. He said his book will be very valuable, and people will search for it and print it and reprint it many times, and it will be very valuable. I only wished I could see how people learn from it and print it. And he said that the words he wrote are very profound, for they are principles.

Comment: Dov, you put a lot of thought, time, and effort into this answer and I really appreciate it....but I'm looking for a very specific quote

Comment: @יהושעק I did a search for "ספר תורה" as well as it being abbreviated as ס"ת in all the seforim: Sichas Ran, Chayei Moharan, Shivchei HaRan, Nesias HaRan as well as all Rav Nachman's seforim that he helped with - Likkutei Moharan, Likutei Halachos etc. and nothing of this nature came up. I am inclined to think that either it has been embellished or was only a verbal testimony...

Comment: Wow, @Dov, that's pretty thorough! If the quote doesn't show up before Motzi Shabbat (Israel time) I'll give you the bounty

Comment: Thank you very much @יהושעק - thanks for asking such a fun question!

Answer (score 0):

פרי מגדים אורח חיים. קנ״ג. ס״ק כד

he says if you cannot learn gemara without selling the sefer tora
it’s allowed

Comment: What connection does this have to Likkutei Moharan?

Comment: according to reb nachman.     likutei maharan is as important

Comment: That's exactly my understanding, @user19400! But where does he say this?

Comment: @Dov Rav nachman wanted his talmidim to learn Likutei Moharan like a Gemara (English book Tzadik states this) , hence user19400 comment of it being as important